# Getting less or more rows of what i should get after the re.findall search

Tags: python, regex

I have unprocessed text and i want to extract the gender of the patient from it, but I end up having either less or more rows, how should I handle such bug?

```
fil = data['transcription']
print(fil)
```

output:

```
0       SUBJECTIVE:,  This 23-year-old white female pr...
1       PAST MEDICAL HISTORY:, He has difficulty climb...
2       HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS: , I have seen ABC ...
3       2-D M-MODE: , ,1.  Left atrial enlargement wit...
4       1.  The left ventricular cavity size and wall ...
                              ...                        
4994    HISTORY:,  I had the pleasure of meeting and e...
4995    ADMITTING DIAGNOSIS: , Kawasaki disease.,DISCH...
4996    SUBJECTIVE: , This is a 42-year-old white fema...
4997    CHIEF COMPLAINT: , This 5-year-old male presen...
4998    HISTORY: , A 34-year-old male presents today s...
Name: transcription, Length: 4999, dtype: object
```

and this is the code to extract the gender from the text

```
import re

gender_aux = []
for i in fil:

    try:
        gender = re.findall("female|gentleman|woman|lady|man|male|girl|boy|she|he", i) or [" "]
    except:
        gender_aux.append(' ')
#         pass

    gender_dict = {"male": ["gentleman", "man", "male", "boy",'he'],
               "female": ["lady","female", "woman", "girl",'she']}

    for g in gender:
        if g in gender_dict['male']:
            gender_aux.append('male')
            break
        elif g in gender_dict['female']:
            gender_aux.append('female')
            break
        else:
            gender_aux+=[' ']
            break
print(len(gender_aux))            
print(gender_aux)
```

If I delete the **or [" "]** or the **else** i get 4967
,otherwise I end up having 5032, and actually I should receive ***4999*** total instances

output:

```
4967 or 5032 #it should be 4999 when i do print(len(gender_aux))
['female', 'male', 'male', ' ', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', ' ', 'male'...]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I forgot to add: Why not take advantage of the functionality provided by Pandas for this?

Comment: @AMC which funtionality? 0.o

Comment: Pandas offers some regex/text manipulation methods. Couldn’t you use named capture groups or two different regex, and simplify things drastically? I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you don't have a conversion to `lower()` or a `flags=re.IGNORECASE` which could make a difference on your final word count.

The main problem is when `re.findall` doesn't match any gender in the string, so your
for loop would end up not running. To avoid that I check if there are any matches from
`re.findall` on that line, if not, just append your blank string.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

text = pd.Series([
    "SUBJECTIVE:,  This 23-year-old white female pr...",
    "PAST MEDICAL HISTORY:, He has difficulty climb...",
    "HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS: , I have seen ABC ...",
    "2-D M-MODE: , ,1.  Left atrial enlargement wit...",
    "1.  The left ventricular cavity size and wall ...",
    "HISTORY:,  I had the pleasure of meeting and e...",
    "ADMITTING DIAGNOSIS: , Kawasaki disease.,DISCH...",
    "SUBJECTIVE: , This is a 42-year-old white fema...",
    "CHIEF COMPLAINT: , This 5-year-old male presen...",
    "HISTORY: , A 34-year-old male presents today s..."
])

gender_dict = {"male": ["gentleman", "man", "male", "boy",'he'],
               "female": ["lady","female", "woman", "girl",'she']}

gender_aux = []
for line in text:
    gender = re.findall("female|gentleman|woman|lady|man|male|girl|boy|she|he", line.lower())

    if len(gender):
        for g in gender:
            if g in gender_dict['male']:
                gender_aux.append('male')
                break
            elif g in gender_dict['female']:
                gender_aux.append('female')
                break
    else: # no gender match
        gender_aux.append(' ')

print(len(gender_aux))
print(gender_aux)
```

Output

```
10
['female', 'male', ' ', ' ', 'male', 'male', ' ', ' ', 'male', 'male']
```